# jQuery event triggered by space

Tags: javascript, key-bindings, keycode, qualtrics

I'm trying to have a next button disabled untill 30 seconds after the space bar has been pressed using jQuery in qualtrics. I've tried a lot of suggestions that have already been made, but nothing seems to work. If anyone could help me out here I'd be super grateful, I'm at a real dead end.

Thanks in advance

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
  /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
  var InputId = $("QR~" + this.questionId);
  InputId.style.display = "none";
  this.disableNextButton();
  if (e.keyCode === 0 || e.keyCode === 32) {
    this.enableNextButton.delay(30);
  }
})
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Could you please provide a [MCVE?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Comment: well you do not listen for a keypress anywhere in that code... Next e is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

$ in Qualtrics is referring to prototypejs. 
You would need to run jquery noconflict to be using jquery, and using the correct identifier to match.

Additionally, you have no event handler to capture your keypress.